# How to export .anm files?

Tags: animation, export

I've been trying to mod a game that uses .anm files for animations, and I can't seem to find any way to export .anm files in blender or convert COLLADA files to .anm

Does anyone know how to do this?

PS there was a similar question on this site regarding importing .anm files, but it was not answered and did not answer my question*

Comment: Those are most likely proprietary engine specific files that can only be exported by some sort of dedicated editing studio or deveoplment software for that game.

Comment: They don't seem to be game-specific file types. When looking it up, I found that appearently many older games use this filetype.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use Blender 2.55b you can export as .anm

https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.55beta/
Any version after that had a complete API overhaul and export as .anm likely got lost for some reason or another.

Comment: The anm version I'm trying to export is more recent than 2010

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [ArchEcho's LOLBie addon](https://github.com/ArcEcho/lolbie), it's supposed to import/export files like .skl, .skn and .anm between Blender and League of Legends.

Comment: They already changed the file system of League of Legends to a signed file system, so custom skins are no longer possible either way ^^